# What causes package samplerate not being found in the pkg-config search path?

Tags: go, go-packages

I stumbled upon a problem when I was trying to install gosamplerate for my project. I was following installation manual on the repository https://github.com/dh1tw/gosamplerate but after succesfully installing libsamplerate0, I get error response while trying to execute go get github.com/dh1tw/gosamplerate:

```
# pkg-config --cflags  -- samplerate
Package samplerate was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `samplerate.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'samplerate' found
pkg-config: exit status 1
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This particular error is unrelated to Go and indicates `samplerate.pc` isn't in the pkgconfig search path. You may have installed libsamplerate under `/usr/local` or somewhere else that is outside the default `pkg-config` search path.

Options:

1. Install libsamplerate from your distribution (if it exists) so `samplerate.pc` is installed in one of the default pkgconfig directories.
2. Set PKG_CONFIG_PATH to enable `pkg-config` to find `samplerate.pc`:

First, find where the `samplerate.pc` is installed (maybe `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`?). Then set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

`pkg-config` should find the config now.

3. Manually rebuild and install libsamplerate in using `./configure --prefix /usr`. This will install it along other system libraries, but makes it much harder to uninstall. **NOT RECOMMENDED**